# Spring Boot requiresUnpack is not upacking at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I'm building an executable jar via the spring-boot maven plugin.  I need to unpack one of the dependent jar so that xml files can be properly read at runtime.  I followed the documentation regarding unpacking libs.  My plugin config is as follows:

```
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <requiresUnpack>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.deep6analytics.pipeline</groupId>
                        <artifactId>pipeline-services-ctakes</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                </requiresUnpack>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

I checked the contents of the jar and verified that the unpacking information was encoded in the jar:

```
$ zipnote target/pipeline-apps-annotation-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep -C 1 UNPACK
@ BOOT-INF/lib/pipeline-services-ctakes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
UNPACK:1e6eda0ca9f1b740c4aba6058cac74a5084f1706
@ (comment above this line)
```

According to the documentation, at runtime, I expected to see a "spring-boot-libs" directory within my $TMPDIR:

> Specify each library as a <dependency> with a <groupId> and a <artifactId> and they will be unpacked at runtime in $TMPDIR/spring-boot-libs.

However, when I run the application, I check the $TMPDIR and do not see the unpacked directory.  As a consequence, my application fails to start:

```
ls -la $TMPDIR

drwxr-xr-x    3  staff      102 Aug 10 23:40 pipeline-apps-annotation-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar-spring-boot-libs-96fe7360-b23b-4caa-a2ce-75aa0300a417
drwxr-xr-x    3  staff      102 Aug 10 23:27 pipeline-apps-annotation-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar-spring-boot-libs-a06a2373-0694-42e9-bee1-29191b3b764a
drwxr-xr-x    4  staff      136 Aug 10 20:54 sp_update
drwx------    2  staff       68 Aug 10 11:30 ssh-azEJDYkZH6ho
drwxr-xr-x    3  staff      102 Aug 10 15:05 tomcat.104726406473930572.8085
drwxr-xr-x    3  staff      102 Aug 10 23:38 tomcat.1527552147767629466.8080
drwxr-xr-x    3  staff      102 Aug 10 23:13 tomcat.1546871599966723864.8080
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong, or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is a little misleading. The unpacked directories are there:

```
drwxr-xr-x    3  staff      102 Aug 10 23:40 pipeline-apps-annotation-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar-spring-boot-libs-96fe7360-b23b-4caa-a2ce-75aa0300a417
drwxr-xr-x    3  staff      102 Aug 10 23:27 pipeline-apps-annotation-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar-spring-boot-libs-a06a2373-0694-42e9-bee1-29191b3b764a
```

Those directories should contain the jars files that you have marked as needing to be unpacked from your executable jar.

I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6624) to correct the documentation.

Comment: Ok - I also thought the jar would be "exploded" so that each of the resources within the jar would reside as a file on disk.  So some clarity around what "unpacking" actually entails would helpful.

As a follow on - how do I extract the resources within the jar onto the file system so they can read directly?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to do it, but you can access a resource via ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream() and then write it out to a file. You can do that without the intermediate unpacking step, though

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using an infrastructure that recurses through nested xml documents - it assumes that all the included documents reside on the file system.  So there isn't anything I can do to change that fact.  So the short of it is that I need these files pulled from the jar and placed on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

On linux it is just /tmp folder. This variable : $TMPDIR did not worked for me